# unix facility to intercept gethostbyname(3) and fake return

Tags: shell-scripting

i want a programme to do this thing .

```
fakeresolv www.example.com=1.2.3.4 -- wget www.example.com/abc
```

this way i can test vhost's of my webserver without setting up dns records . i want to limit this effect on one process or one process tree . i want uninvolved processes resolve hostnames with the regular resolver .

wget here is for example . i want this facility to wrap many other programmes .

i think LD_PRELOAD and ptrace(2) are candidate approaches . but have small experience on the detail implementation . if there is another programme does something similar , i may use that as a reference . so before i want to start my own code , what existing project is good to look at ?

Comment: i am aware of `wget --header "Host:www.example.com" 1.2.3.4/abc` . but not satisfied .

Comment: So, editing /etc/hosts is overkill for your needs, right?

Comment: how to make different processes see a different /etc/hosts ? with namespaces(7) ? @glennjackman